# Display percentage labels in Seaborn displot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm hoping to display the percentages in each subplot using Seaborn displot. Using below, I plot each unique value in `Item` in different rows. While the each unique value in Num takes up the x-axis. The values from `Label` are currently displayed, but I'm also hoping to display the percentages as text.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,2,3,3,1,3],
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','B','B','C','C','B','B','A','C','A','B','A','C','A'],  
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right','Down','Right','Up','Up','Right','Down','Left'],        
   })

g = sns.displot(data = df, 
           x = 'Num', 
           row = 'Item', 
           hue = 'Label',
           row_order = ['Up','Down','Left','Right'],
           discrete = True,
           multiple = 'fill',
           aspect = 4, 
           height = 2,
           )

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.xaxis.labelpad = 8
    ax.yaxis.labelpad = 8
    ax.tick_params(which = 'both', width = 0.8, labelsize = 8)
    
for p in g.axes.flat:
    txt = str(p.get_height().round(2)) + '%'
    txt_x = p.get_x() 
    txt_y = p.get_height()
    g.ax.text(txt_x,txt_y,txt)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get a concrete image of the output. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Figure is attached. So bottom plot would display 100% for 1, 50% for 2 and 100% for 3.

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you referring to the composition of this result? `cols = df['Item'].unique();for c in cols:;print(df[df['Item'] == c][['Label','Num']])` I cannot understand the basis for calculating the percentages, even with your comment.

Comment: If I change the y-axis from count to percentage does that help? I'm essentially hoping to display the percentage as text. So it's the proportion of each unique value in Label. Most only have 1 unique value. But for the

Comment: `txt = str(p.patch.get_height()) + '%';txt_x = p.patch.get_x();txt_y = p.patch.get_height()`You can use this to get the value, but you can't use

Comment: Is your question still open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PercentFormatter` labels the y-axis in percentage format.  To get access to the patches with the individual bars, you need to loop through the patches of each ax. Each bar has a xy position, a height and a width.  The height indicates the percentage.  The center of the bar can be calculated using x, y and half the width and height.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Num': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3],
    'Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
    'Item': ['Up', 'Left', 'Up', 'Left', 'Down', 'Right', 'Up', 'Down', 'Right', 'Down', 'Right', 'Up', 'Up', 'Right',
             'Down', 'Left'],
})

g = sns.displot(data=df,
                x='Num',
                row='Item',
                hue='Label',
                row_order=['Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right'],
                discrete=True,
                multiple='fill',
                aspect=4,
                height=2,
                )
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.xaxis.labelpad = 8
    ax.yaxis.labelpad = 8
    ax.tick_params(which='both', width=0.8, labelsize=8)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1)) # x ticks at multiples of 1
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1)) # percentage using 1 for 100%
    ax.set_ylabel('Percentage')
    for p in ax.patches:
        h = p.get_height()
        if h > 0: # skip empty bars
            txt = f'{h * 100:.2f} %'
            txt_x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
            txt_y = p.get_y() + h / 2
            ax.text(txt_x, txt_y, txt, ha='center', va='center')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.09) # make a bit more room for the label
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot with percentages]

Comment: Apologies, I did't even see this answer!